TensorFlowInferenceInterface in flutter
I have an object detection code in Android, I want to convert it to Flutter to use it for IOS as well
public static Classifier create(
            AssetManager assetManager,
            String modelFilename,
            String[] labels,
            int inputSize,
            int imageMean,
            float imageStd,
            String inputName,
            String outputName) {
        final TensorFlowImageClassifier c = new TensorFlowImageClassifier();
        c.inputName = inputName;
        c.outputName = outputName;

        // Read the label names into memory.
        Collections.addAll(c.labels, labels);

        c.inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(assetManager, modelFilename);

        // The shape of the output is [N, NUM_CLASSES], where N is the batch size.
        final Operation operation = c.inferenceInterface.graphOperation(outputName);
        final int numClasses = (int) operation.output(0).shape().size(1);

        // Ideally, inputSize could have been retrieved from the shape of the input operation.  Alas,
        // the placeholder node for input in the graphdef typically used does not specify a shape, so it
        // must be passed in as a parameter.
        c.inputSize = inputSize;
        c.imageMean = imageMean;
        c.imageStd = imageStd;

        // Pre-allocate buffers.
        c.outputNames = new String[]{outputName};
        c.intValues = new int[inputSize * inputSize];
        c.floatValues = new float[inputSize * inputSize * 3];
        c.outputs = new float[numClasses];

        return c;
    }

Called:
create(
                                getAssets(),
                                "file:///android_asset/xxx",
                                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.yyy),
                                INPUT_SIZE,
                                128,
                                128,
                                "input",
                                "InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1")

org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface
This class is not found in flutter, what should I replace it with?

You can use flutter_tflite package to infer tflite models in flutter. Since you are using this for object detection, You need to figure out more than that.

Load the model and the labels. This can be done with the flutter_tflite
get the image and prepare the image for your model (crop the image for the model input size and make a byte array as required by the model)
run the model with the image.
Clean the outputs (if it need nms) and get the bounding boxes.

There are some examples in the flutter_tflite package. But it all depends on your model type.
